# How to use 1 administrator account for multiple sites?

Tags: administrator, user, login

I need to find a solution for joomla backend administrator login to make easier for multiple site.

Let`s say i have a dozen of Joomla sites and their administrator account is XYZ and the password is 123.

When i want to change password for XYZ administrator account; I need to do this manually for all my Joomla sites.

I look for solutions to make this process automated or make it easier. 
I guess LDAP could be a good solution but I never tried that one, also I do not have AD server right now.

Would Open ID help me to achieve my goal or do you have any other ideas?

Any suggestions much appreciated. Thank You already.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you need is your own [Authentication Plugin](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Creating_an_Authentication_Plugin_for_Joomla).  The example given shows authentication being done against the user table, but you could just as easily check if the password is equal to todays date - whatever, or *wherever*, you want to check.  Once you have it working to your liking, just install and enable it on all your sites.  Having both enabled, you'll probably want the standard user authentication first, then if it fails, it goes on to try yours.

For example, if you want to make one of your sites the "master", you could use this code in the plugin to always check THAT database for your master credentials:

```
$options = array(
    'driver' => 'mysqli',
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'user' => 'mymasterusername',
    'password' => 'mymasterpassword',
    'database' => 'mymaindatabase',
    'prefix' => 'xyz_',
);
$maindb = JDatabase::getInstance($options);
```

Comment: YW...it's customary to accept the answer if it works for you so that others will benefit.

Comment: Have not tried it yet.